# GIT Same File with Different Name in Different Branch

Tags: git

Looking into GIT Workflow, I've created a repository with `master` and `develop` branch for my client. Now, for the time, *the client has decided to run both the production and development API from the same server*. So my solution was to create **two directories**, one with `development` configuration and another with `production` files as below:

```sh
# development directory
root@client: pwd
>> /develop/my-api

root@client: git clone -b develop --single-branch https://gitlab.com/client/repository.git

# production directory
root@client: pwd
>> /production/my-api

root@client: git clone -b master --single-branch https://gitlab.com/client/repository.git
```

I cloned only a single branch because I/others will hardly be using `PUSH` from the server. Now I have the `main` file - whose content is the same in both `master` and `develop` branches.

I decided to **rename the file** as `main-dev.py` and `main-prob.py` in the branches so that **later I can simply use `ps -aux | grep main-dev.py` to find which process is associated with which file**, as I will be requiring the particular PID later on.

So, from this scenario I want to understand the following things:

1. Is this process correct, and is generally accepted in the development community?
2. If no, then what is the way.
3. **Is there a way to make `GIT` know that both `main-dev.py` and `main-prob.py` are the same files with a different name in `develop` and `master` branches respectively?**

Options I have thought of so far:

1. Update my `.gitignore` file in both `master` and `develop` to exclude the other file.
2. Create/Modify a file named `main.py` and change the file name manually later.
3. Find the `PID` using `ps -aux | grep main.py` and identify PID from the directory path.

Option **#1** seems okay, but I am not sure if this is accepted. **#2** seems hectic and might be problematic. **#3** is probably the best - unless I/others accidentally delete/update on the wrong PID.

Comment: Use a CI tool instead of using a mix of git and folders.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Can you suggest some resources? As I'm new to GIT, and not sure how to do this.

Comment: Git isn’t really suited for this sort of deployment. Search “ci tool” for ideas.